# Static header layout in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to know how to  reload content without refresh the header. I created a small sample code below.

**Header.php**

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
     <body>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="index2.php">News</a></li>
       </ul>
```

**index.php**

```
    <?php 
      include("header.php");
    ?>
    <div>
     This is contents 1
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index2.php**

```
<?php 
      include("header.php");
    ?>
    <div>
     This is contents 2
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I assume index and index2 page as content pages.

When I click home or news link, content pages loads, but header.php also refresh every time when click it.

I want to know, how to load content pages without get fresh header.php when click home links.

Any ideas to do it with php or javascripts?

Comment: Congrats on making it work too. If you can accept my answer it would help me also :D, Trying to build up a trust-able account :)

Answer (score 2):

**MAJOR EDIT**

Using @Mihir's code. I came up with a working sample.

**index.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function go_to_home()
  {
      $('#content').load('home.php');
      return false;
  }

  function go_to_news()
  {
      $('#content').load('news.php');
      return false;
  }
  </script>

</html>
```

**header.php**

```
<div>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <button onclick="go_to_home();">home</li>
    <button onclick="go_to_news()">News</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**home.php**

```
<div>
  <p>I am at home</p>
</div>
```

**news.php**

```
<div>
  <p>This is my news</p>
</div>
```

This works now!! :D

Comment: Thank for idea, @Lorenzo Magno. i didn't get it well. If you can provide small example,I can go through it.

Comment: No problem, I'll add a code in a while to help you out.

Comment: I appreciate your help @Lorenzo Magno. I got it. If it not bother to you. I have one more question. I already developed a site. so it have few external php files. So, there are any other method to call external php files?

Comment: Yes it does and I'm working on it. The added answer by @Mihir I think is a more correct code. That's what I was working on. You can follow his guide, and if it's okay to give my answer an upvote, I'm glad to help:)

Comment: I tried his code, its not working for me. im not  more familiar with ajax :(

Comment: Let's see if he will edit, I'll comment there, I too have a code and maybe after a while I'll give it if i get it to work myself. :)

Comment: I didn't seperate the main.js like what @Mihir did, but you could :)

Comment: Great job @LorenzoMagno :)

Comment: @Mihir , thank you, I lacked some knowledge too and almost came up with a wrong answer earlier, using your code helped me so much in coming up with a correct answer. :)

Comment: @LorenzoMagno Thanks you very much for this.It work perfectly. :D

Comment: If you liked my answer and it's correct give me a check! I'll always help you also if you need :) @sj2012 lol we commented on the same time. If it's not much of a hassle give me a check it would help me too :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use AJAX for that kind of thing. What you're trying to do is essentially SPA (Single Page Application). While it is alright to build your own SPA using simple AJAX request to fetch the partial view, I'd suggest you to learn React or Angular.

To achieve the desired effect, you can use simple XHR in vanilla javascript or you can use jQuery's `$.ajax`, `$.post`, `$.get`. If you opt for jQuery, you'll be using this kind of approach heavily throughout your application.

Master.php file-

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
  </body>
  <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
</html>
```

content.php -

```
<div>
  <p>Content 1 goes here</p>
</div>
```

header.php -

```
<div>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li id="home">home</li>
    <li id="content">content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

main.js -

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "content.php",
    cache: false
  })
  .done(function( html ) {
    $( "#content" ).html( html );
  });
});
```

This is only a general idea of how it would work. I have not tested the code, please don't expect it to run as it is. You'll want to use `onclick` listeners on links in your navbar to call AJAX and render the correct partial view.

Comment: +1 , This was the code I was working on. Though he did not test the code I think @sj2012 will get the gist of it.

Comment: @LorenzoMagno Yes. It's not tested and neither it is complete. But it will definitely give sj2012 a direction to work towards.

Comment: @Mihir i tried it, but it doesn't work, Im not more familiar with ajax

Comment: @Mihir , The track sj2012 is on is a little hard for him since he is a beginner in ajax, I'm not an expert but I can get it to work, if you would edit your code i think it'll help him a lot. I'm trying to work on it on my own too :)

Comment: @sj2012 That's perfectly alright! I'll give you three steps to get comfortable with web development. 1. Learn PHP page life cycle, build sample applications. 2. Learn javascript and why it is used. 3. Learn AJAX and why it is used. Once you do these steps, you'll be flying just fine. Good luck!

Comment: @LorenzoMagno Yes, agreed. I have only so much time to spend since I'm working. If you write a sample code for him, that'd be great!

Comment: I have one now! @mihir